# Is it possible to insert HTML into a libreoffice cell?

Tags: html, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm currently trying to insert HTML into a LibreOffice Calc Cell.

So far, I've tried something like:

`<b>Hello</b> <i>world</i>`

But currently this is rendered as plain text instead of rich html text.

Is there any way to solve this and possibly add an image too?

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice formulas do not use HTML syntax.

However, you can select "Hello" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to make it bold, then select "world" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for italics. To insert an image, go to *Insert > Image*.

Substitution and formatting could also be done with a macro, for example, use a regex to find `<b>...</b>`, strip the markers, and change that TextPortion formatting to bold.

Another thing you can do is copy from a webpage and paste HTML formatting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Calc will do its best to convert into LibreOffice formatting, including hyperlinks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was trying to use HTML because I'm currently using Python UNO to replace values in a sheet and wanted to use HTML in a particular cell. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use Python-UNO to set [character properties](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1style_1_1CharacterProperties.html) of a text portion. For example, set `CharWeight` to `com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD`. To do this, first import the BOLD constant.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to load your HTML into a temporary writer doc and then copy its content to the target calc cell. This works with basic formatting, but not with images, though.

```python
def InsertHtml2Calc(sHtml, calcDoc, cell):
    oStream = ctx.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.io.SequenceInputStream", ctx)
    oStream.initialize((uno.ByteSequence(sHtml.encode()),))

    prop1 = PropertyValue()
    prop1.Name  = "FilterName"
    prop1.Value = "HTML (StarWriter)"
    prop2 = PropertyValue()
    prop2.Name = "InputStream" 
    prop2.Value = oStream
    prop3 = PropertyValue()
    prop3.Name = "Hidden" 
    prop3.Value = True    
    tmpWriterDoc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL("private:stream", "_default", 0, (prop1, prop2, prop3)) 

    tmpWriterContr = tmpWriterDoc.CurrentController 
    oVC = tmpWriterContr.ViewCursor
    oVC.gotoStart(False)
    oVC.gotoEnd(True)

    calcDoc.CurrentController.select(cell)
    calcDoc.CurrentController.insertTransferable(tmpWriterContr.Transferable)
    tmpWriterDoc.close(True)

# doc contains a calc doc
InsertHtml2Calc('Hello <b>bold</b> <i>italics</i><br>2nd line', doc, doc.Sheets.getByIndex(0).getCellByPosition(5,5))
```